# Can WordPress WP_Query return custom field post meta?

Tags: wordpress, meta, custom-fields

For some reason, I cannot get WP_Query to return the custom field values of posts. I can get the post thumbnails using `get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, array(50,50))`, but I cannot get the custom field data using `get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true)`.

A stripped-down version of what I'm trying to do:

```
<?php
    $keys = array('Show Date','Birth Year','Origin');

    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr><th>Title</th>';
    foreach( $keys as $key ) {
        echo '<th>' . $key . '<th>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';

    $myquery = new WP_Query( 'post_type=post' );
    if( $myquery->have_posts() ) : while( $myquery->have_posts() ) : $myquery->the_post();

        $title = get_the_title();
        echo '<tr><td>' . $title . '</td>';

        $values = array();
        foreach( $keys as $key ) {
            $values[] = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true);
        }
        foreach( $values as $value ) {
            echo '<td>';
            echo $value;
            echo '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';

    endwhile; endif;

    echo '</table>';
?>
```

Also available here:
http://pastebin.com/at8S2THs

Even with all non-essential code removed, I cannot make this work. I know you can use parameters like `meta_key` and `meta_value` in a query to narrow down the results, but I just want to display all values for the keys I specify, if they exist, for each post.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

** SOLUTION FOUND **

Just needed to add `global $post;` after the start of the loop. Thanks to @Kimikaze on the WP support forum for providing the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I can't find the data I need in wordpress, I always find it helpful to print the Global $post object to screen, so I can see if my data is making it to the page.

```
Global $post;
echo "<pre>";
 print_r($post);
echo "</pre>";
```

All the helper methods or "hooks" are usually just interacting with this (or another) global object. Check the output of this on $post (and maybe your $values array) for data you're looking for and if it's there, you can just reffer to it directly, like the post title for example

```
$post->title
```

Another thought, The third parameter of get_post_meta() makes it return a single string when set to true, what do you get when it's set to false?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Printing the $post object was helpful, in that it confirmed what I suspected: The custom field data is not being returned by my WP_Query. Guess I'll have to build a custom MySQL query... And to answer your question, when the third parameter is set to false it still doesn't return anything. Each custom field only contains one value anyway, so no need for an array there.

Comment: Another couple thoughts: when printing $post to screen, try doing so in different regions of the page, once I was pulling my hair out over missing data only to realize that it was getting queried properly but since another wordpress request happened mid page , the $post contents were overwritten with new query results.  

Also, for writting custom queries, check out what people say about the $wpdb object in combination with setup_postdata() method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem has to do with the values you're using as meta keys. To retrieve the data with get_post_meta() you'll want to pass in the actual meta_key values, which are probably 'show_date', 'birth_year', and 'origin' since the meta_key value doesn't handle uppercase letters or spaces. Try changing to those values where you're setting the $keys array:

```
$keys = array('show_date','birth_year','origin');
```

If that doesn't work, it might be worth checking in the database (in the wp_postmeta table) to confirm the actual meta_key values.

Comment: Good thoughts, but no dice. Using the lowercase_underscore format doesn't make a difference, and the meta data is definitely there. In fact, I'm able to call it on a single post page template using code like `$artist_birth = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Birth Year', true)` without any trouble at all.

Comment: When I add some metadata into the database and then run the code from pastebin I get the expected results (i.e. it prints a bunch of metadata). Any chance you can paste the code that adds the metadata? Also, where is this code running within your WP install?

Comment: Would you mind terribly testing out this plugin: http://mynewsitepreview.com/plugins/sorttablepost_v4.0beta.zip - I'm trying to add support for custom fields to the latest version this plugin.

Comment: Sorry, should have also told you how to use the plugin. The shortcode `[sorttablepost meta="Custom Field Key,Another Custom Field Key,Yet Another" nothumb="true" nocats="true" notags="true"]` should output a table that lists all of your post titles, post dates, and whatever custom fields you identify in the meta option.

Comment: Figured it out, with the help of someone on the WP forum. Turns out I just needed to add `global $post;` right after the start of the loop. Thanks for your help, though!